# Generating an API Client with Swagger OpenAPI 3 with OAuth2 Client Credentials

Tags: openapi, swagger-codegen

I am using the Swagger OpenAPI 3.0.2 version for describing my API.

I built swagger-codegen 3.0.5 snapshot from the Swagger gihub repo.

I want a Java client that will obtain the OAUTH2 token for a grant type of client_credentials. I want client credentials because this is one machine talking to another, I am not asking a user for their credentials. I have the following bit in my spec file:

`securitySchemes:
    oAuth2ClientCredentials:
      type: oauth2
      description: Standard OAUTH2
      flows:
        clientCredentials:
          tokenUrl: my_token_url
          scopes: {}
security:
  - oAuth2ClientCredentials: []`

I want a Basic Authentication header with the client ID and the client secret in the standard base64 encoding with the grant_type as a URL encoded form. This is pretty standard OAuth2 authentication.

I seem to sometimes get code for the OAuth authentication and sometimes not. The python library has nothing for OAuth other than me proving the access token by hand. The Java library doesn't have it unless I ask for retrofit as the base library, but it generates a Bearer Authentication header, rather than a Basic Authentication Header. Retrofit2 doesn't even work, the handlebars template has an illegal character in it that handlebars barfs on.

So what do people do to get their access tokens when they have a client ID and a client secret? Do you craft the code to get the access token by yourself? Or is there some magic way of getting swagger-codegen-cli to generate the code for me, depending on the libraries that I use?

If anyone has managed to get swagger-codegen-cli to generate everything they need for OAuth 2 client credentials with an OpenAPI 3.0 specification, please let me know.

Comment: Open an issue in the Swagger Codegen repository at https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues.

Comment: That was my next stop. But I thought I'd try here first.

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution in the meantime? I am having the same issue.